# If the support of a function is contained in a Borel set, is the support of its derivative also contained there?

Tags: real-analysis

Let  $f$ be a function such as $\operatorname{supp}(f)\subset Q$ where $Q$ belongs to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}^d$

Do we have $\operatorname{supp}(f')\subset Q$?

Comment: I suppose $f'$ is the derivative? Classical or distributional? What are the assumptions of $f$? Have you tried to solve the problem yourself?

Comment: $f'$ is the classical derivative of $f$

Comment: Okay, then all you need is the fact that the complement of support is the largest open sets in which the function is identically zero.

Comment: I don't get it, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that $Q$ is a Borel set is irrelevant here. If $f : \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable, then $\operatorname{supp}(f') \subseteq \operatorname{supp}(f)$.

To see this, suppose $x \not\in \operatorname{supp}(f)$, then $f(x) = 0$. Furthermore, as $\operatorname{supp}(f)$ is closed, there is an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ such that $f|_U = 0$. As $f'(x) = f|_U'(x)$, $f'(x) = 0$. So, if $x \not\in \operatorname{supp}(f)$, then $x \not\in \operatorname{supp}(f')$, i.e. $\operatorname{supp}(f)^c \subseteq \operatorname{supp}(f')^c$.